# Is this the right place to ask questions about iPhone?

Tags: support

I am facing a problem in syncing my iphone contacts with my google account. Is this forum a good place to ask related questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, from the [FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq):

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.

Questions should relate to User Experience design, HCI research and broadly related forms of design and study.

[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) on the other hand covers issues like iOS support.